# Crawl log error: Access is Denied

Tags: search, crawling, alternate-access-mapping, access-denied

i am getting the issue as below when i check the sharepoint log files,

> The start address https://**.****.co.im cannot be crawled. Context:
>   Application 'Search_Service_Application', Catalog 'Portal_Content'
>   Details: Access is denied. Verify that either the Default Content
>   Access Account has access to this repository, or add a crawl rule to
>   crawl this repository. If the repository being crawled is a SharePoint
>   repository, verify that the account you are using has "Full Read"
>   permissions on the SharePoint Web Application being crawled.
>   (0x80041205)

I also checked the Event log and i get the issue as:

> Alternate access mappings have not been configured.  Users or services
>   are accessing the site `http://svrname` with the URL
>   http://**.****.co.im.  This may cause incorrect links to be stored or
>   returned to users.  If this is expected, add the URL
>   http://**.****.co.im as an AAM response URL.  For more information,
>   see: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=114854"/>

I have done AAM settings as posted [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/68158/sharepoint-2010-http-to-https-redirection-iis-7-5).

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method 1 from [this link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896861) did the trick for me.

> Click Start, click Run, type regedit, and then click OK.
>
> In Registry Editor, locate and then click the following registry key:
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\MSV1_0
>
> Right-click MSV1_0, point to New, and then click Multi-String Value.
>   Type BackConnectionHostNames, and then press ENTER.
>
> Right-click BackConnectionHostNames, and then click Modify.
>
> In the Value data box, type the host name or the host names for the
>   sites that are on the local computer, and then click OK.
>
> Quit Registry Editor, and then restart the IISAdmin service.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use SSL (https) whenever specifying your content sources in SharePoint search.

Also, the second error just means that users and services are using the `http://servername` url to access to the site. It's more of a warning than an error. I constantly see that on my farm, but I ignore it.

Comment: I changed it to `http` even that doesnt work. Same error message `Access denied`

Comment: What is the search service account? Does it have access to the content database?